# Getting connection refused error when trying to communicate through HTTPS

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter 2.13 and have tried with http client 3.1 and http client 4 with HTTPS protocol and am getting error as connection refused:

> Error :org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to 132.186.197.59:1003 refused at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)

Comment: What error is visible in stacktrace?

Comment: Error :org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://132.186.197.59:1003 refused at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)

Comment: Connection problem occurs both for http client 3.1 and 4? If yes, it could be a true connection problem :)

Comment: thanks michaldo, there was an issue in my machine on ssl connection using the port, it has been resolved and now its working fine in both http client 3.1 and 4

Answer (score 0):

There is a connectivity issue in your machine on the port used by SSL.

Ensure connectivity is ok from JMeter machine to target machine on HTTPS port